# Uber cool Linear Gradients in CSS3

Tags: html, css, gradient

Is it possible to create (without images), really cool looking linear gradients like the ones you see in the Ribbon menu controls?[image]

Does anyone know of any tutorials, articles resources or samples that demonstrate/show off this kinda gradient?

Answer (score 7):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

I've used this in the past.  It is nice because it makes a number of flavors of the gradient, since exact syntax isn't well defined yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Background Gradient:**

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #ededed, #ededed) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
/* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ededed));
/* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ededed);
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ededed, endColorstr=#ededed);
/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ededed, endColorstr=#ededed)";
```

**Text Shadow Effect:**

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```